# Wierd VUEX states behaviouro

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am just a beginner with VUEJS, i encountered issue when tried using **vuex states**. There is a module named **'login'** and with in **'login'** module there are following **states**:

```
state:{
  email: '',
  password: '',
  toast: ''
}
```

i was trying to access states in **vue** application using **this.$store.state.email** which gave the value **undefined**. After all day suffering, banging my head around, i tried **this.$store.state.login.email** and it worked.

Shouldn't it be working the first way?

Comment: It’s not weird at all. You’re using modules and the email is only available in your login module and not the root state, so you need to “dot” into the login module first. Read the docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell without the full code, but I suppose you are probably using modules, and login is one of the modules of the main store, so to access the login module you have to go through the main store then the module it self, hence the `this.$store.state.login.email`

Here is a link if you want to know more about [Vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html).

Ps : You can also access your login module properties as computed properties like so.

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {

   computed: {
       ...mapState ({
           email: state => state.login.email,
           password: state => state.login.password,
           ...
       }),
   },

}
```